# Regex to go beyond 10 numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying to match with regex, it has to be a number and it shouldn't go beyond 10 numbers. Anything else don't show!

```
match(/[^0-9]|[0-9]{10,80}/)
```

The first part works, meaning it's NOT a number, but the second part doesn't, if it's above 10.

http://jsfiddle.net/qwtmnuey/1/

I can do it in another way but I want it the regex way.. thank you!

```
(function($){
    $('input').on( 'keypress', function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if ( char.match(/[^0-9]|[0-9]{10,80}/) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Uh... `<input type="number" maxlength="10" />`?

Comment: so you mean if value is only number and length is 0 to 10 then it should proceed else it will prevent default?

Comment: You're checking one character at a time so the `{10,80}` setting is redundant there. You need to check the value as a whole.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `maxlength` doesn't work with number input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, that's the issue. I managed to resolve it now by adding another if check to the value.

Comment: @MonicaLI8 note that your implementation doesn't prevent user from pasting incorrect value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if `char` matches the regex, but you mean to check if the entire contents of the `input` match your regex. If you add `id="myinput"` to your `<input>` and in your javascript you add

```
var inputdata = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
```

Then you can check if `inputdata` matches your regex it does work.

Also you're checking for `{10,80}` which means between `10` and `80` but you can also change that to `{10,}` which means `10` or `more`